# Pyramid slider JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I need to create pyramid slider. 
[image: pyramid slider]

As you can see in my current implementation, I need to have a center image that is in top of rest of items. They form a pyramid structure. Also images are placed under each other and this effect is breaking everything because I need to transform them ( elements on the right side of center image needs to have translateX(-100px) and on the left side translateX(100px). I need to have animations when changing items but due to translateX it looks awful. I created this one using http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ but maybe someone know such slider with out of box funcionality ?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://idangero.us/swiper or just look for a 3d carousel.

With some customization, I finally made it how I wanted :)